# How to return the "mock implementation" of a singleton?

Tags: java

EJ says the following:

> Its' impossible to substitute a mock implementation for a Singleton
>   unless it implements an interface that serves as its' type.

So, a class like :

```
 public class TestSingleton implements TypeReturnable{
    public static final TestSingleton INSTANCE = new TestSingleton();
    private TestSingleton(){
    }
    public static getInstance(){
    return this.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

...

```
public interface TypeReturnable{
TestSingleton getType();
}
```

or does it include passing type as a parameter to the class while its' construction.I am confused as to how is it possible to substitute an implementation when it implements an interface that serves as its' type?

Comment: `TypeReturnable getType();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write

```
public enum Singleton implements ISingleton {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

where the singleton is passed via dependency injection.

```
MyTested mt = new MyTested(Singleton.INSTANCE);
```

however to test this you can do

```
ISongleton mockSingleton = createMock(ISingleton.class)
MyTested mt = new MyTested(mockSingleton);
```

I suggest you avoid having

- mutable singletons (Pass a mutable object during construction)
- globally addressed singletons (again use DI instead)

Answer (score 0):

The condition mentioned is [necessary, not sufficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency).

In order for you to be able to mock a singleton, you need to:

- Make the singleton implement an interface or extend some superclass (interface is cleaner)

  - since the singleton has a private constructor, you cannot extend the singleton class itself
- Only use that singleton through that interface

  - i.e. when assigning it into your variable, that variable must be of the interface type not the singleton type itself; when calling methods, only call methods of the interface
- Don't access the singleton through static methods (i.e. `TestSingleton.getInstance()`) all across your code

  - such call cannot be done in a way that uses the mock instead of the singleton and must be replaced with the mock use
  - you'll need to pass the singleton instance (or the mock instance when mocking the singleton) either through constructor, arguments, setter, or using a dependency injection framework